# How do you change the executed javascript file in azure website?

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service

Using git deployment to deploy to azure I have a .deployment file with the contents.

```
[config]
command = bash deploy.sh
```

And a deploy.sh with contents

```
#!/bin/bash

# ----------------------
# KUDU Deployment Script
# Version: 0.1.7
# ----------------------

# Helpers
# -------

exitWithMessageOnError () {
  if [ ! $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "An error has occurred during web site deployment."
    echo $1
    exit 1
  fi
}

# Prerequisites
# -------------

# Verify node.js installed
hash node 2>/dev/null
exitWithMessageOnError "Missing node.js executable, please install node.js, if already installed make sure it can be reached from current environment."

# Setup
# -----

SCRIPT_DIR="${BASH_SOURCE[0]%\\*}"
SCRIPT_DIR="${SCRIPT_DIR%/*}"
ARTIFACTS=$SCRIPT_DIR/../artifacts
KUDU_SYNC_CMD=${KUDU_SYNC_CMD//\"}

if [[ ! -n "$DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE" ]]; then
  DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE=$SCRIPT_DIR
fi

if [[ ! -n "$NEXT_MANIFEST_PATH" ]]; then
  NEXT_MANIFEST_PATH=$ARTIFACTS/manifest

  if [[ ! -n "$PREVIOUS_MANIFEST_PATH" ]]; then
    PREVIOUS_MANIFEST_PATH=$NEXT_MANIFEST_PATH
  fi
fi

if [[ ! -n "$DEPLOYMENT_TARGET" ]]; then
  DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=$ARTIFACTS/wwwroot
else
  KUDU_SERVICE=true
fi

if [[ ! -n "$KUDU_SYNC_CMD" ]]; then
  # Install kudu sync
  echo Installing Kudu Sync
  npm install kudusync -g --silent
  exitWithMessageOnError "npm failed"

  if [[ ! -n "$KUDU_SERVICE" ]]; then
    # In case we are running locally this is the correct location of kuduSync
    KUDU_SYNC_CMD=kuduSync
  else
    # In case we are running on kudu service this is the correct location of kuduSync
    KUDU_SYNC_CMD=$APPDATA/npm/node_modules/kuduSync/bin/kuduSync
  fi
fi

# Node Helpers
# ------------

selectNodeVersion () {
  if [[ -n "$KUDU_SELECT_NODE_VERSION_CMD" ]]; then
    SELECT_NODE_VERSION="$KUDU_SELECT_NODE_VERSION_CMD \"$DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE/src\" \"$DEPLOYMENT_TARGET\" \"$DEPLOYMENT_TEMP\""
    eval $SELECT_NODE_VERSION
    exitWithMessageOnError "select node version failed"

    if [[ -e "$DEPLOYMENT_TEMP/__nodeVersion.tmp" ]]; then
      NODE_EXE=`cat "$DEPLOYMENT_TEMP/__nodeVersion.tmp"`
      exitWithMessageOnError "getting node version failed"
    fi

    if [[ -e "$DEPLOYMENT_TEMP/.tmp" ]]; then
      NPM_JS_PATH=`cat "$DEPLOYMENT_TEMP/__npmVersion.tmp"`
      exitWithMessageOnError "getting npm version failed"
    fi

    if [[ ! -n "$NODE_EXE" ]]; then
      NODE_EXE=node
    fi

    NPM_CMD="\"$NODE_EXE\" \"$NPM_JS_PATH\""
  else
    NPM_CMD=npm
    NODE_EXE=node
  fi
}

##################################################################################################################################
# Deployment
# ----------

echo Handling node.js deployment.

# 1. KuduSync
if [[ "$IN_PLACE_DEPLOYMENT" -ne "1" ]]; then
  "$KUDU_SYNC_CMD" -v 50 -f "$DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE/src" -t "$DEPLOYMENT_TARGET" -n "$NEXT_MANIFEST_PATH" -p "$PREVIOUS_MANIFEST_PATH" -i ".git;.hg;.deployment;deploy.sh"
  exitWithMessageOnError "Kudu Sync failed"
fi

# 2. Select node version
selectNodeVersion

# 3. Install npm packages
if [ -e "$DEPLOYMENT_TARGET/package.json" ]; then
  cd "$DEPLOYMENT_TARGET"
  eval $NPM_CMD install --production
  exitWithMessageOnError "npm failed"
  cd - > /dev/null
fi

##################################################################################################################################

# Post deployment stub
if [[ -n "$POST_DEPLOYMENT_ACTION" ]]; then
  POST_DEPLOYMENT_ACTION=${POST_DEPLOYMENT_ACTION//\"}
  cd "${POST_DEPLOYMENT_ACTION_DIR%\\*}"
  "$POST_DEPLOYMENT_ACTION"
  exitWithMessageOnError "post deployment action failed"
fi

echo "Finished successfully."
```

iisnode.yml is not in the repository but the generated contents are

```
nodeProcessCommandLine: "D:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\0.10.24\node.exe"
```

web.config is not in the repository but the generated contents are

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <webSocket enabled="false" />
    <handlers>
      <add name="iisnode" path="server.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode"/>
    </handlers>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="NodeInspector" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^server.js\/debug[\/]?" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="StaticContent">
          <action type="Rewrite" url="public{REQUEST_URI}"/>
        </rule>
        <rule name="DynamicContent">
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True"/>
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="server.js"/>
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The server.js is what I'd like to change to index.js  Adding a web.config file may fix this but I'd like to know a configuration way to do it if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll find the easiest way to do this would to simply include a web.config file with your application. Here are some things you can investigate if you'd like to dig into it further.

- Http Handlers can be added via the portal. I don't know much about iisnode besides how it is configured automatically in Web Sites, however, it may be possible to pass the full path to iisnode.exe and pass in the path via the additional arguments section.
- You can investigate to see if there is an environment variable which gets set for the server.js value. Navigate to the Kudu Console by going to https://**[your-site]**.scm.azurewebsites.net/Env and login using your deployment credentials. If there is an environment variable with a value of server.js you might be able to add it to the appsettings section with a new value (I think it does validation to confirm it doesn't already exist thought), or you might be able to change the Environment variable as part of  your deploy.sh script.

Comment: thanks for the link to the https://[your-site].scm.azurewebsites.net/Env tools!  That's exactly what I needed azure to have.